# Ensure Entity Framework can connect to database before connecting

Tags: .net, entity-framework, localdb

mHow to ensure that the database can be connected from Entity Framework BEFORE the connection will be tried?

If the database (LocalDB here) doesn't exists on the location where the connection string is pointing, I might get `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.`

The application must open even without the database and not crash.

I wonder how I can check the database connection and where that should be done. I have unit of work where the context will be initiated first time:

```
Public Class UnitOfWork
    Implements IDisposable

    Private ReadOnly _context As myEntities
    Public Sub New()
        _context = New myEntities 
        'DO I TRY TO CHECK HERE THE CONNECTION/HOW OR IS IT ALREADY TOO LATE?
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: How about simple exception catching?

Answer (score 0):

You can, in a try/catch block, test opening the the connection.

```
_context.Database.Connection.Open();
```

If it opens successfully your're good to go. Just make sure you close the connection. New'ing up a new context doesn't try the connection so you need to test just after you've got your new context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see that DataContext would have the Database property but maybe DataContext.DatabaseExists method could be used for that.